# Ext js 4.0.7 disable tab with click functionality

Tags: extjs

Trying to add click event to disabled tab,below code works for chrome but nor for mozilla and IE,even jquery bind method with click does not respond,here disabled tab should not activate on click but opens new window 
which is in popwinmanagetabs

```
var tabs2 = Ext.createWidget('tabpanel', {
        activeTab: 1,
        width: 1200,
        height: 750,
        cls:'mgtabcls',
        id:'mgtab',
        plain: true,
        defaults :{
            autoScroll: true,
            bodyPadding: 80
        },
        items:[
            {
                title:'<div id="popupwinlink" style="cursor:pointer;font-weight:bold;font-size:25px;color:black;" onclick="javascript:popwinmanagetabs();">+</div>',
                id:'addIcon',
                cls:'addtablink',
                style:{cursor:'pointer'},
                disabled:true
            }
        ]
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I were you, I would stay inside the framework. Using a clickable DIV is completely outside ExtJS framework; warranty void.

I would use my own pseudo disable instead, something along the lines of

```
// instead of tab.disable()
tab.pseudoDisabled=true; 
tab.addCls('x-tab-disabled');

// instead of tab.enable()
tab.pseudoDisabled=false;
tab.removeCls('x-tab-disabled');

// If tab is disabled, disallow access:
beforeactivate:function(tab) {
    if(tab.pseudoDisabled) {
        popwinmanagetabs();
        return false;
    }
}
```

I didn't test the code; maybe I forgot some edge cases (e.g. auto-activation of the first non-disabled tab after initComponent), but because you stay inside the framework, at least you don't have to worry about browser compatibility.

Comment: return false does not work,It still activates the tab.

Comment: [The docs tell us that we should be able to prevent the event from beforeactivate](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.0.7/#!/api/Ext.AbstractComponent-event-beforeactivate), [but the code seems ambiguous](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.0.7/source/Card.html#Ext-layout-container-Card-method-setActiveItem). This may be an issue with your version of ExtJS.

Answer (score 1):

Below code worked for me

```
var onTabHeaderClick = function(btn, e) {
    popwinmanagetabs();
    e.stopEvent();
};
Ext.getCmp('addIcon').tab.on('click', onTabHeaderClick);
```